# postgres fails to uninstall

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, postgresql

while trying to uninstall postgresql with

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
```

I received the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'postgresql' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postgresql-common (154ubuntu1) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                       * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2015-07-08 11:16:50 PDT FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
                                                                                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.3:
 postgresql-9.3 depends on postgresql-common (>= 142~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-9.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the same happens when I try to purge postgres, what is happening here and how can I properly remove postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

---

### My solution

the **Short way**

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/postgresql
sudo rm /etc/init/postgresql.conf
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
```

---

or the **Long way**

- Open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-common.postinst`

  ```
  sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-common.postinst
  ```
- Search the line with the start command:

  ```
  if [ -x "/etc/init.d/postgresql" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/postgresql.conf" ]; then
          invoke-rc.d postgresql start || exit $?
  fi
  ```
- comment the block out

  ```
  # if [ -x "/etc/init.d/postgresql" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/postgresql.conf" ]; then
  #        invoke-rc.d postgresql start || exit $?
  # fi
  ```
- Remove the package again.

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove postgresql
  ```

---

### Explanation

During the removal of the `postgresql`, the script `postgresql-common.postinst` is called. The script tries to start the service `postgresql` and will fail `invoke-rc.d postgresql start` (ask me not why).

This must be prevented. Either by changing the conditions by which the code is executed. Or by the removal of the code itself.

Comment: the short version worked perfectly for me thanks!

Comment: @TCulos I have added the block **Explanation** at the end of my answer.